# How can JFreeChart print a scatter point directly on the x axis?

Tags: jfreechart, scatter-plot, scatter

I try to make a scatter chart but the data point is not exactly at the (2,0) coordinate and only partly visible.
The image shows the generated output from JFreeChart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGpZW.png

But it should be like this (made with GIMP):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqrnh.jpg

Does anybody know how to do it?

thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else, here is the solution, which didn't satisfy me completely but is acceptable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/70TbB.png

The interesting lines of code to do so were:

```
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerMargin(0);
```