# JFreeChart Scatter Plot moving data between series

Tags: java, jfreechart, cluster-analysis, k-means, scatter-plot

Sorry if this question is a little nonspecific but im very new to using JFreeChart and have a mediocre understanding of it. Essentially im trying to create an application that depicts the kMeans clustering algorithm step by step on a scatterplot with randomly generated points. I want to have the program show which clusters points belong to by using color. Would it be possible to move points from one dataset to another when the algorithm determines it belongs in a different cluster? If not could i get a suggestion on what would be a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This example removes `N/2` items from *Original* and adds them to *Moved* with each button press.

[image: iamge]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13794076/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430747
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048652
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208657
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736553
 */
public class ScatterAdd extends JFrame {

    private static final int N = 8;
    private static final int SIZE = 345;
    private static final String title = "Scatter Add Demo";
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Original");
    private final XYSeries added = new XYSeries("Moved");

    public ScatterAdd(String s) {
        super(s);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Move") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
                    XYDataItem item = series.remove(0);
                    if (item != null) {
                        added.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
        this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis(), true);
        adjustAxis((NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis(), false);
        xyPlot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    private void adjustAxis(NumberAxis axis, boolean vertical) {
        axis.setRange(-3.0, 3.0);
        axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.5));
        axis.setVerticalTickLabels(vertical);
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            series.add(rand.nextGaussian(), rand.nextGaussian());
        }
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(added);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScatterAdd demo = new ScatterAdd(title);
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```